# What's the most efficient way to parse large XML and generate a Hive table?

Tags: python, hive

I'm trying to parse a very large XML file produced by scientists, generate a set of field values that I'll extract from that XML, store the results in S3, and then make a Hive table based on those field values.

The XML is very large -- say, ~100M and about 3 million lines of text. But the format is predictable, and looks like this:

```
<Butterfly>
    <Name>Swallowtail&</Name>
    <HomePage>https://example.com/butterflies/swallowtail/</HomePage>
    <TaxonomyID>54321</TaxonomyID>
    <Grouping>Papilionidae</Grouping>
</Butterfly>
```

So let's say each Butterfly is a row, and each child is a field in my table. I use Python to generate the field values and delimit them with a '\t'. Using xml.etree.ElementTree I parse each row from top to bottom, strip out whitespace and tabs in data using something like:
    text_value = re.sub('\s+', ' ', field.text).rstrip()

Then, I dump the large string of field values to s3, and my final step is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS butterflies (
Name STRING,
HomePage STRING,
TaxonomyID BIGINT,
Grouping STRING,
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://butterflies/test_parsed_xml/';
```

The Python step is VERY inefficient and takes *forever.* There's *got* to be a smarter way of doing this! Any tips? Also, the db doesn't have a logical partition.

I've tried python to generate a large field value string, which I push to s3. Is there a smarter SerDe or better way to do this?

```
    field_values = ''
    row_count = 0
    for row in self.root_node:
        field_count = 0
        for field in row:
            if field.tag in self.schema[field_count]:
                if field.text:
                    text_value = re.sub('\s+', ' ', field.text).rstrip()
                else:
                    text_value = u''
                field_values = (field_values + text_value + '\t')
                field_count += 1
            else:
                raise ValueError()

        field_values = field_values + '\n'
        row_count += 1
        print("Processed row number {}".format(row_count))
    # Finally, code which pushes the huge string to s3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way available, there is third party serde which Parse xml files and stores as hive table in hdfs.

> The problem is, your xml file is not a valid xml file. you need remove `&` and make sure all the tags are closed. i.e. `HomePage`

**Reference:**

https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources

- Download the latest jar from there. 
  https://search.maven.org/search?q=hivexmlserde
- move the jar into your HDFS directory `hdfs dfs -put hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar`
- Load the jar file `add jar hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar`
- make sure the jar is loaded using `list jars;`

if you are able to see jar, then you have done things properly else you missed something.

Now, create the table using above serde as mentioned below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS butterflies (
Name STRING,
HomePage STRING,
TaxonomyID BIGINT,
`Grouping` STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.Name"="/Butterfly/Name/text()",
"column.xpath.HomePage"="/Butterfly/HomePage/text()",
"column.xpath.TaxonomyID"="/Butterfly/TaxonomyID/text()",
"column.xpath.Grouping"="/Butterfly/Grouping/text()"
)

STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

location '/tmp/test_xml/table/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<Butterfly",
"xmlinput.end"="</Butterfly>"
);
```

After this move your xml file to `/tmp/test_xml/table/` location.

Comment: I fixed the faulty XML. The real problem is empty elements e.g. <TaxonomyID></TaxonomyID>. This is very interesting and I'm going to check it out!

Comment: @Malos it's gonna be represented as `NULL`

Comment: @gaurang_shah: I get an error which looks like this: ExecScript.sh: line 3: Butterfly: No such file or directory. Any ideas why that might happen? It's as if it can't find the root node of the XML and assumes it's a file or something. Any idea?

Comment: at which point are you getting error. did you `download jar` & `move to hdfs` & `add to hive` & `verified` and then created `external table` and then `moved you xml file` to location` and finally run `select * from table_name`